# Why is threading.Event a function instead of class?

Tags: python, multithreading, python-2.7, events

For the project which I am working on, we use python 2.7.
I need to implement synchronization between two treads, one signals and the other awaits. So I have used isntance of `threading.Event` for this purpose. I injected this event object into another object (lets say instance of `AnotherClass`) via its constructor. In constructor of `AnotherClass` I wanted to validate the input parameter so I checked its type if it is actually instance of `threading.Event`. This is where I was surprised, since this fails.

Code looks something like this:

```
from threading import Event

class AnotherClass(object):
    def __init__(self, event):
        if not isinstance(event, Event):
            raise ValueError("event is not instance of threading.Event"):
    ...

event = Event()
another_object = AnotherClass(event) # raises exception
```

When I start to debug the problem, I found out that `threading.Event` is actually a function which returns instance of `threading._Event` class:

```
>>> from threading import Event
>>> Event
<function Event at 0x0000000002B529E8>
>>> e = Event()
>>> e
<threading._Event object at 0x0000000002AE0358>
```

On python documentation page its stated it is a class.[image]
This does not seems logical to me. This is not the case for e.g. threading.Thread. It is actually a class and it has constructor:

```
>>> Thread
<class 'threading.Thread'>
>>> dir(Thread)
['_Thread__bootstrap', '_Thread__bootstrap_inner', '_Thread__delete', '_Thread__exc_clear', '_Thread__exc_info', '_Thread__initialized', '_Thread__stop', '__class__', '__delattr__', '__dict__', '__doc__', '__format__', '__getattribute__', '__hash__', '__init__', '__module__', '__new__', '__reduce__', '__reduce_ex__', '__repr__', '__setattr__', '__sizeof__', '__str__', '__subclasshook__', '__weakref__', '_block', '_note', '_reset_internal_locks', '_set_daemon', '_set_ident', 'daemon', 'getName', 'ident', 'isAlive', 'isDaemon', 'is_alive', 'join', 'name', 'run', 'setDaemon', 'setName', 'start']
```

Of course, I can omit this check and let the code fails later when some non-existent method is called on passed object, but I would like this code to failed as soon as possible.

So, to summarize my question:

**Could someone explain what is the reason behind this implementation of `threading.Event`?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know what's going on with the documentation online, but the screenshot you've posted is for the class `threading._Event`, even though it says it's for a class `threading.Event`. `threading.Event` is a factory function which returns an instance of `threading._Event`. I think this is wildly unintuitive, particularly since the documentation makes no typographical distinction between `threading.Event` and `threading._Event`, and you are right to be confused. https://docs.python.org/2.7/library/threading.html#module-threading Here's the page that says `threading.Event` is a factory function (true) and it says to see also "Event Objects" which are actually `class threading._Event`s and which are described erroneously in the docs as being `class threading.Event`.

I did some googling and it looks like the docs have been broken in this way for many years.

Threading Events are created sensibly in later releases of Python.